# PayPal Express Checkout - get transaction data at a later time

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I implemented PayPal Express Checkout - works great. For some transactions I would like to get the Address status (verified or not) at a later time (after a week or two). How can I accomplish this in PHP? (I have saved the token, transactionId at the checkout).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GetTransactionDetails](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/gettransactiondetails-api-operation-nvp) for that.

If you're going to be working with PayPal services quite a bit I'd recommend taking a look at my [PHP class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/overview-of-php-class-library-for-paypal/).  It makes all of their API calls a breeze.

Comment: I'm using your class, respect for making it open source.

Comment: Thanks.  I plan on getting it on Github before long.  I just need to get more comfortable with Git in general.